# Bumblebee pointclouds (.yaml) calibration files

Tags: ros, calibration, yaml, bumblebee, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I am currently using the Bumblebee2 to extract pointclouds with the stereo_image_proc node on ROS. The problem is that i get very bad results on the disparity image, most of it is grey, even after playing with some parameters like the speckle filter...I used the calibration files (.yaml) that i could have with the stereo calibration node and as a consequence i get bad pointclouds. I would like to know if anyone succeded in having good pointclouds from the bumblebee2 using the calibration (.yaml) files and if it is possible to use the calibration files given by pointgrey or to publish directly the rectified images through ROS using triclops.

Thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59795/bumblebee-pointclouds-(.yaml)-calibration-files/) by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In our lab we successfully calibrated two different kinds of Bumblebee2 stereo cameras (2.5 and 3.8 mm focal length) with the [ROS stereo calibration tool](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration). We used the `-k 6` option to allow for more parameters in the distortion model.
We run the [camera1394stereo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394stereo) driver for the camera and [stereo_image_proc](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc) to generate rectified images and point clouds.
Regarding the parameters for stereo_image_proc we followed [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc/Tutorials/ChoosingGoodStereoParameters). We had to increase the `disparity_range` to 128. The point clouds look quite nice (see the video on the [viso2_ros wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros)).

Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on 2013-04-02**:
Thank you very much Stephan, i will try this tomorrow and tell you about the results.
Ps : Your pointcloud is very good !